# Japser Report WIndow Issue

Tags: javafx, jasper-reports

I have javafx application that print to pdf. I works fine on linux (UBUNTU 20.04)

But when I run It On WIndow I get

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3897)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1878)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2623)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:557)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:943)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor170.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1852)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:114)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:82)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:251)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:272)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:156)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:145)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:758)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:1074)
        at com.sample.service.TransService.printTrans(TransService.java:473)
        at com.sample.service.TransService.saveTrans(TransService.java:298)
        at com.sample.service.TransService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c1f7da87.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
        at com.sample.service.TransService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$860dd8c4.saveTrans(<generated>)
        at com.sample.service.TransService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c1f7da87.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at com.sample.service.TransService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$861491a6.saveTrans(<generated>)
        at com.sample.controller.MainController.handleTrans(MainController.java:583)
```

I have included jaspter report maven dendencies

> ```
>      <dependency>
>         <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
>         <version>6.17.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
>         <version>6.11.0</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

The error comes from when this line of code is excuted

> JasperReport jasperReportInstance = session.getJasperReportInstance();
>
> JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportInstance, parameters, new
> JREmptyDataSource());

When I call fill report I get the error On on window

I am using java 17 oracle jdk jafax 17.0.1.

Any on with idea?

Comment: [mcve] please, including the complete stacktrace .. where is the relation to javafx?

Comment: If you format the trace and code [as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) rather than quoted, it is easier to read.

Comment: Added Full Stack Trace @kleopatra

Comment: Do you need to [“recompile from source JRXMLs”](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/11081).  Try creating a small plain Java app without JavaFX and see if you can create a report.

Comment: I have found the issue. 
In Linux this works  

JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/sable/inv.jasper"));

IN Windo The Paths Doesn't work. How Can I resolved This FOr Both Platform?

Comment: The resolution of resources isn't really platform-dependent as far as I am aware.  So, I don't see a reason for the lookup to work on one platform but not another.  Review [resource lookup in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other) and follow the suggestions in the troubleshooting section, that may or may not help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.
The issue was my jasper report was using custom font which was not found when load the report. I tried to use build in jasper report font if you have included jasperreports-fonts. Go to jar and find fonts.xml replace font name you were using with the default one. Compile .jrxml and run jasper report

There were no issues with URL in the class path. If your report where in

```
src/main/resource/reports/customer.jaspper
```

Then Print that report I used

```
 JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("reports/customer.jasper"), parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

The solution works well also when running from jar

I hope will help someone.